# create a custom method and call it in the routes.rb in ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am trying to do a redirect from url to another in rails 4. before doing the redirect I want to process one of the parameters and change its value in certain conditions(or not change it), then do a redirect. That's what I have tried so far

```
#routes.rb
get 'Client/:f_name/:l_name', to: redirect { |params, req|
        "clients_area/#{params[:f_name].parameterize}/#{my_process_params_method(params[:fname], params[:lname]) }"
      }
```

But I keep getting the error

> undefined method `my_process_params_method' for ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fe1db4e4e08>

What am I doing wrong here? or is there a better solution?

The thing is that I must do this redirect at the level of the route and not create an action to take care of that.

Comment: But what prevents from changing this parameters inside your action/method?

Comment: why don't you create a controller method and redirect wherever you want from there?

Comment: these are legacy urls that we have to redirect for seo reasons. and they must be done this ways. I cannot do a redirect of a redirect as this is bad for  seo reasons as well

Answer (score 1):

I have realized the mistake. the method in the module should have been declared as a class method (`self.method_name`) and that the method should be called this was `MyModul.my_process_params_method(var1, var2)`